# Taking a generic enum or any type that can do "as usize" in a function

Tags: rust

I don't know what the answer to this would look like and that's why the title is so ambiguous.

It is possible in rust to cast enum types to numbers using "as" like so

```
enum ExampleEnum { A, B, C }

fn main() {
    println!("{}", ExampleEnum::B as usize);
}
```

Is there a way to make a generic function that can take any data type that can do that? Or some Trait that encapsulates that functionality? Maybe in an "unsafe" way (transmute?) ?

```
enum ExampleEnum { A, B, C }

fn what_n(x: ???) -> usize {
    x as usize
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", what_n(ExampleEnum::B));
}
```

Comment: Does this help at all? https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html "In order to express that we want a generic function to take all arguments that can be converted to a specified type T, we can use a trait bound of Into<T>."

Comment: @ZanLynx it's alright, kind of annoying to have to implement "Into<usize>" for every enum but it could be fine https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4c4b4b0f4604f7381cc7b28ca7f821bb

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/type-layout.html#primitive-representations